# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to read an file in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to read an XML file and parse it, for that I had used SAX parser which requires file as input to parse. For that I had stored my XML file in Entity called XMLDocs with following property

XMLDocs Entity Name
  name : Property of string type
  content : property of blob type (will contain my xml file)

Reason I had to store file like this as I had not yet provide my billing detail to google

Now when I try to open this file in my I am getting error of permission denied..

Please help me, what I have to do...

You can see that error by running my app at

www.parsepython.appspot.com

Comment: Could you please share the code that is leading to this error?

Comment: Below is code that leads me to error

Answer (score 1):

It probably thinks that the data string you are providing is a filename.

You may be able to pass it a file-like object which wraps the data, for example instead of this:

```
parser.parse(str(q.content))
```

Try this:

```
parser.parse(StringIO.StringIO(str(q.content)))
```

Comment: Thanks Saxon for ur suggestion

But I m getting below error

**NameError: global name 'StringIO' is not defined**

Comment: You need an 'import StringIO' near the top of your .py file

Comment: Use comments to respond directly to another answer. Don't create a new answer.